# Why is Notpad++ opened from IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run my spring-app in IntelliJ I get the normal output in the run-tool-window. The very first greyich line contains the complete command run to start the app. It is clickable so that the full thing should be expanded and displayed inline. But unfortunately my IntelliJ is somehow configured to open the thing in Notpad++ instead.

**Q:** How can I make IntelliJ open the thing inline instead?

[image]